# Random 3-D Array where first element ist not in array

Tags: python

i want to generate a random 3d Array in python like this:

```
 jobs = [
 [(5, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)], #job1
 [(5, 2), (2, 1), (1, 4)], #job2
 [(1, 4), (2, 3)] #job3]
```

The condition is, that the first element in a job should not be duplicated. The second element in a job can be have a random value.
That means for the example, that job1 should not look like this:

```
[[(5,3), (5,2), (5,2)]]
```

I have tried with following code:

```
job_count = 5
jobs = []
for x in range(job_count):
  jobs.append([])
  for y in range(random.randint(2,5)):
    jobs[x].append([])
      for z in range(2):
          if z == 0:
              random_value = random.randint(1,10)
              while random_value not in jobs[x]:
                  random_value = random.randint(1,10)
              jobs[x][y].append(random_value)
          else:
              jobs[x][y].append(random.randint(1,50))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your jobs is essentially a zip of a random sample and some random choices:

```
import random

job_count = 5

jobs = []
for _ in range(job_count):
    n = random.randint(2,5)
    jobs.append(list(zip(random.sample(range(1,11),n),random.choices(range(1,11),k = n))))

for job in jobs:
    print(job)
```

Typical output:

```
[(5, 8), (1, 9), (2, 1), (8, 9), (4, 1)]
[(3, 8), (7, 3)]
[(2, 2), (6, 10)]
[(3, 4), (8, 6), (10, 1), (9, 4)]
[(1, 10), (3, 4)]
```